# Disable checkPrimaryKeyUnicity for a QgsDataSourceURI

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

How can I make a PostgreSQL `QgsDataSourceURI` set up with `setConnection` and `setDataSource` not check the primary key unicity?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setParam` method:

```
myQgsDataSourceUri.setParam("checkPrimaryKeyUnicity", "0")
```